# In Android Studio, how to pass an image as a parameter to a function with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I am making a "business card" app which basically displays my photo with my contact info underneath. The contact info consists of rows, with each row displaying the app icon (eg: Instagram) on the left, and my info on the right (eg: My Instagram username).

I've made separate composable functions for each app and called them and it works fine.

For example:-

```
@Composable
fun InstagramContactInfo() {
    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(start = 30.dp, end = 30.dp, bottom = 16.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.icons8_instagram_48),
            contentDescription = "Instagram Icon",
            modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp)
        )
        Text(
            text = "@username",
            fontFamily = FontFamily.Monospace,
            color = Color.White,
        )
    }
}
```

**But** I want to create a function that just accepts an image as the icon, a userhandle as a String, and then displays this exact same thing.

How do I pass an image as a parameter?

PS: I was trying to embed the resource Id but it doesn't work

```
@Composable
fun ContactInfo(icon: String, handle: String) {
    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(start = 30.dp, end = 30.dp, bottom = 16.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.${icon}),
            contentDescription = "App Icon",
            modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp)
        )
        Text(
            text = handle,
            fontFamily = FontFamily.Monospace,
            color = Color.White,
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be getting drawable from string like below. But its not compile time safe. If the particular image not available in drawable folder it might throw `Exception`
If you have drawable with id `R.drawable.your_icon` , you should pass as "`your_icon`"

```
@Composable
fun ContactInfo(icon: String, handle: String) {
    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(start = 30.dp, end = 30.dp, bottom = 16.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
     Image(
                painter = painterResource(
                    LocalContext.current.resources.getIdentifier(icon, "drawable", LocalContext.current.packageName)),
                contentDescription = "App Icon",
                modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp)
            )
         Text(
            text = handle,
            fontFamily = FontFamily.Monospace,
            color = Color.White,
        )
    }
}
```

But if its possible to use Resource Id directly, you can have it like below instead of string.

```
@Composable
fun ContactInfo(@DrawableRes icon: Int, handle: String) {
    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(start = 30.dp, end = 30.dp, bottom = 16.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(icon),
            contentDescription = "App Icon",
            modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp)
        )
        Text(
            text = handle,
            fontFamily = FontFamily.Monospace,
            color = Color.White,
        )
    }
}
```

Here you can pass like `R.drawable.your_icon` .

Comment: So the second example is better practice?
Also, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes second one is better practice than the first example. Because in first one , it uses resource reflection. And it might throw exeception if id not present.